# Is the virtual machine of OpenJDK pluggable?

Tags: java, jvm, graalvm

In previous times it was easy. We used the words *java* and *virtual machine* synonymously.

Now we have Hotspot VM (Oracle JDK), the [OpenJDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK) Server VM, the [Eclipse OpenJ9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJ9) VM and the [Graal VM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GraalVM).

I am a little bit confused. Does OpenJDK has or is a runtime environement which could be used in conjunction different virtual machine implementations? Is there a standard interface for this or is it simply supported by OpenJDK.

I am asking as the output of running `java -version` for the two OpenJDK variants and the Graal VM contains in every case `OpenJDK rintime`:

```
> /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk11-openj9/Contents/Home/bin/java -version
openjdk version "11.0.1" 2018-10-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.1+13)
Eclipse OpenJ9 VM AdoptOpenJDK (build openj9-0.11.0, JRE 11 Mac OS X amd64-64-Bit Compressed References 20181020_7 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
OpenJ9   - 090ff9dc
OMR      - ea548a66
JCL      - f62696f378 based on jdk-11.0.1+13)

> /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk11/Contents/Home/bin/java -version
openjdk version "11.0.1" 2018-10-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.1+13)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.1+13, mixed mode)

> /opt/graal/graalvm-ce-1.0.0-rc10/Contents/Home/bin/java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_192"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_192-20181024123616.buildslave.jdk8u-src-tar--b12)
GraalVM 1.0.0-rc10 (build 25.192-b12-jvmci-0.53, mixed mode)
```

I know there is a plenty of documents on this question on the web but none of them I read gave a secured state of knowledge on this topic.

Comment: Sort-of. See [`ScriptEngine`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngine.html) and [`ScriptEngineManager`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngineManager.html). The JDK has mechanisms to plug-in additional **languages**. The VM itself isn't normally swappable.

Comment: I'm confused by your question, OpenJDK includes the VM, so how would you want to use it in conjunction with another VM?

Comment: And what are you talking about "synonymously"? There's always been the Sun JVM, Hotspot, Excelsior, WebSphere...

Comment: By the way, there have always been multiple implementations of Java, from almost the beginning. Some have fallen away, and others have emerged.

Comment: Studying this will help: [*Java Is Still Free*](https://medium.com/@javachampions/java-is-still-free-c02aef8c9e04)

Comment: FYI, Wikipedia offers a long list of [past and present Java implementations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Java_virtual_machines).

Comment: I added the output of java -version for the various OpenJDK variants.

Comment: So it looks like the question is; What is an "OpenJDK Runtime Environment" ?

Comment: Yes, this is the correct question. But I realized this only today. I misunderstood the term "Runtime Environment".

Answer (score 4):

OpenJDK is quite modular, a prime example is the Graal compiler, which can be plugged via the JVMCI interface and completely replace the top tier JIT compiler (C2). Graal still uses HotSpot for the battle-tested infrastructure: object model, class loading, profiles, debugging, GC...

There are a few "interfaces"/components:

- The VM interface (libjvm), a bunch of low-level methods to e.g. deal with native sockets, open files, create threads...
- The native bindings (JNI), a well-defined interface between Java and the native world.
- Java itself, including the standard library, an incredible amount of Java is actually implemented in Java.
- libjava, native implementations for lots of native methods in the standard library, it's completely VM agnostic.

To implement a new VM you'd need to implement the VM interface, JNI and the bytecode compiler/interpreter, then you can reuse all the code in Java + libjava without porting/re-implementing anything e.g. you get all the IO, NIO, sockets, even the classloaders for free.

GraalVM is just OpenJDK with superpowers, this includes a state-of-the-art compiler (Graal), a framework to build (fast) programming languages (Truffle) + AOT optimizing compiler (SubstrateVM)... among other goodies.